# Finalizar compra Html + PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou fazendo um site para um trabalho escolar onde preciso criar Listagem de produtos disponíveis no Banco de Dados, e tenha opção de inserir no carrinho de compras.

Até ai está funcionando corretamente, porém quando clico no "finalizar compra" para salvar a compra no banco de dados estão ocorrendo 2 erros de mysqli e não consigo identificara origem.

Segue abaixo a parte do código que criei para isso:

```html
<!-- Inserindo no carrinho de compra -->
<table class="table table-hover" id="tabcar">
      <h1>Carrinho de Compras</h1>
      <thead>
        <tr  bgcolor="#AAAAAA">
          <td>Codigo</td> 
          <td>Descriçao</td>
          <td>Valor</td>
          <td>Qntd</td>
          <td >Total R$</td> 
          <td>Remover</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
          <form action="?acao=up" method="post">
      <tbody>
          <?php
              if(count($_SESSION['listaproduto']) == 0 ){
                ?>
                <div align="center">
                <?php echo "<h3><b>Não ha produtos no carrinho</b></h3>";?>
                </div>
                <?php
              }else{
                require("conexao.php");
                foreach($_SESSION['listaproduto'] as $id => $qtd){
                  $sql = "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE codigo= '$id'";
                  $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());
                  $ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr);

                  $codigo = $ln['codigo'];
                  $descricao = $ln['descricao'];
                  $valor = $ln['valor'];
                  $total = $ln['valor']*$qtd;
                  $subTotal += $total;
                  echo '<tr>
                          <td>'.$codigo.'</td>
                          <td>'.$descricao.'</td>
                          <td>'.$valor.'</td>
                          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="prod['.$id.']" value="'.$qtd.'" /></td>
                          <td>'.$total.'</td>
                          <td><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" href="?acao=del&id='.$id.'"></a></td>
                        </tr>';
                }   
              }?>
      </tbody>
      <!--Parte para finalizar compra -->
      <?php
 if(isset($_POST['enviar']))
 {
    $SqlInserirVenda = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into venda(valorTotal) Values('$subTotal')");
    $IdVenda = mysqli_insert_id();

    foreach($_SESSION['listaproduto'] as $ProdInsert => $Qtd):
    $SqlInserirItens = mysqli_query("Insert into itensvenda(IdVenda,IdProduto,Qtde) Values('$IdVenda','$ProdInsert','$Qtd')");
    endforeach;
    echo "<script>alert('Venda Concluída')</script>";
 }
?>
</table>
<div align = "right">
<form action="" enctype ="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <?php echo '<h3> Total: R$'.number_format($subTotal,2,",",".").' </h3>'  ?>
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Finalizar Pedido" />
</form>
```

E estes são os dois erros:

Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Se alguma parte do codigo faltou para poder me ajudar, informar aqui e eu mandarei, desde já muito obrigado!

Comment: O programa está aguardando um valor para o id, e a query que criou está faltando um dos dois valores para ser enviado

Comment: Tem ideia da onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função mysqli_insert_id() espera um conector como parâmetro, ou seja:

```
$IdVenda = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

e mude esta linha

```
$SqlInserirItens = mysqli_query("Insert into itensvenda(IdVenda,IdProduto,Qtde) Values('$IdVenda','$ProdInsert','$Qtd')");
```

para

```
$SqlInserirItens = mysqli_query($conn, "Insert into itensvenda(IdVenda,IdProduto,Qtde) Values('$IdVenda','$ProdInsert','$Qtd')");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, corrigi isso e um erro no BD e deu certo. Valeu!

Answer (score -1):

Marcelo, tente fazer a seguinte alteração:

```html
$IdVenda = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

Comment: Mike, fiz a alteração porem continuam os erros

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: Então Marcelo, como o riki481 falou "O programa está aguardando um valor, e a query que criou está faltando um dos dois valores para ser enviado", você precisar dar uma conferida nos nomes das varáveis e ver se estão corretos.

Comment: Eu coloquei o parametro de conexão no outro msqli_query agora ele mostra a mensagem de compra concluida e não aparece erro, porem não salva no banco de dados, alguma ideia? Os nomes das tabelas estão certinhos

Comment: Ah, verdade, faltou o '$conn' aqui '$SqlInserirItens = mysqli_query($CONN, "Insert into itensvenda(IdVenda,IdProduto,Qtde) Values('$IdVenda','$ProdInsert','$Qtd')");', isso você já corrigiu, certo?

Comment: Corrigi sim obrigado, porem o maior erro era que o Id no banco de dados não estava como auto incremento, mudei isso e o que você falou e resolveu, Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Ah, fico feliz em ter ajudado a resolver seu problema :D

Comment: Eu que agradeço